# ZXing black screen on Oxigen One Plus 3 and Galaxy S7

Tags: android, zxing

I am using ZXing API to read bar codes, but for some reason it just opens a black screen when I try to open the scanner in Oxigen One Plus 3 or Samsung Galaxy S7. I works fine in my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini thought.

I am using 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8', but did try version 1.5 as well.

Any ideas on what may be the case for the black screen here?

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScanBarCodeActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);

    this.zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    zXingScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String barCode = result.getText();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("BAR_CODE_RESULT", barCode);
    returnIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(ScanBarCodeActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
    returnIntent.putExtra("BAR_CODE_RESULT", "");
    returnIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(returnIntent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

Comment: Found the issue. In newer versions of Android the user has to go and manually give permission to the app to use the camera. This is done in Configurations -> Applications -> Permissions.